# loop over files and extract part of filename

Tags: bash

I have a directory with multiple files including .vcf files

I would like to loop the .vcf files but only take part of the filename. E.g. the filenames are

```
R1050C_v1_Non-Filtered.vcf
R1039B_v1_Non-Filtered.vcf
R1071D_v1_Non-Filtered.vcf
```

But the actual sample names are `R1050C_v1, R1039B_v1, R1071D_v1`
I know I can do something like:

```
for sample in *.vcf
do
something --input $sample --output ${i%_Non-Filtered.vcf}_someNewExtension.vcf
done
```

But I have several steps in the script and so ideally want to loop through just the sample names instead of then doing:
`--input  ${i%_Non-Filtered.vcf}_someNewExtension.vcf --output  ${i%_Non-Filtered.vcf}_anotherNewExtension.vcf`

I know I can also do:

```
for sample in *.vcf
do
echo "$sample" "${sample%_*}.vcf"
done
```

Which actually extracts the part that I want but is there a way of say instead of echo saving it into a new variable and then looping over this??

Comment: If you need the modified names only in the body of your loop, just assign them to a new variable. If you need the same data in several loops, I would create an array of the original names and one of the modified names and then use these arrays as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just re-assign the loop variable at the beginning of each iteration:

```
for sample in *.vcf; do
    sample=${sample%_*}
    # do stuff here
done
```

Comment: I'd recommend using different variable names, to avoid confusion; something like `for sampleFile in *.vcf; do sample=${sampleFile%_*}`

Answer (score 3):

If you don’t need to deduplicate the sample names:

```sh
file_names=(*.vcf)
sample_names=("${file_names[@]%_*}")
```

If you **do** need to deduplicate the sample names:

```sh
file_names=(*.vcf)
declare -Ai sample_set=()
for file_name in "${file_names[@]}"; do
  ((++sample_set["${file_name%_*}"]))
done
sample_names=("${!sample_set[@]}")
```

And then just loop through it all you like:

```
for sample_name in "${sample_names[@]}"; do
  echo "Doing something with sample '${sample_name}'."
done

for sample_name in "${!sample_set[@]}"; do
  echo "BTW, sample '${sample_name}' was found" \
       "$((sample_set["$sample_name"])) times."
done
```