# For-loop over glob returns single string instead of list

Tags: bash

I'm trying to loop over images in a directory, but instead of one image per loop, my for-loop only iterates once and the loop variable contains all the images.

```
#!/bin/bash

IMAGEDIR="/home/user/myimages/"

for file in "$IMAGEDIR*.jpg"; do 
  echo $file
  echo "next file"
done
```

Outputs:

```
/home/user/myimages/A.jpg /home/user/myimages/B.jpg /home/user/myimages/C.jpg
next file
```

I would expect it to output:

```
/home/user/myimages/A.jpg 
next file
/home/user/myimages/B.jpg 
next file
/home/user/myimages/C.jpg
next file
```

I've looked at several other questions, and I don't think I should need a nested for loop.

- [How to loop over directories in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107945/how-to-loop-over-directories-in-linux)
- [Looping over directories in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854559/looping-over-directories-in-bash)
- [Loop through files in a given directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23408782/loop-through-files-in-a-given-directory)
- [loop over files and extract part of filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68855783/loop-over-files-and-extract-part-of-filename)

Additionally, I figured out that it works if I use a slightly different format

```
#!/bin/bash

IMAGEDIR="/home/user/myimages/"

for file in "$IMAGEDIR"*.jpg; do 
  echo $file
  echo "next file"
done
```

Why does the first glob return a single string and the second one return a list?

Comment: Putting the glob in quotes prevents it from expanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does the first glob return a single string and the second one return a list?

Because quotation suppresses pathname expansion, but quote removal leaves your glob subject to expansion later.

Consider your first example ...

> ```
> for file in "$IMAGEDIR*.jpg"; do 
>   echo $file
>   echo "next file"
> done
> ```

Parameter expansion applies within double quotes, so it expands `"$IMAGEDIR*.jpg"` to `"/home/user/myimages/*.jpg"`.  The quoting suppresses the significance of `*` for pathname expansion, however, and no other expansions apply, so `"/home/user/myimages/*.jpg"` is the final expanded version.  Which is then subject to *quote removal*, so the first and only value that `file` take in that loop is (literally) `/home/user/myimages/*.jpg`.

In the body of the loop, then, parameter expansion expands `echo $file` to `echo /home/user/myimages/*.jpg`.  The `*` is *not* quoted now, and pathname expansion happens after parameter expansion, so you get one `echo` command with the names of all the matching files as arguments (supposing that there are any matching files).

The difference in your second example is the placement of the quotation marks.  With the `*` outside the quotation marks in the `for` line, you get pathname expansion *there*, resulting in several different values for variable `file` to take on successive iterations of the loop.

Comment: Ah, so it's a case of two wrongs make a very confusing debugging experience.

Comment: Yes, @Cecilia, I can imagine that that was so.  You wanted to leave the `*` out of the quotation marks, but if there was any point to the quotation marks in the first place (and there was) then you should have quoted `$file` inside the loop body.  And those issues combined to disguise both.